# C++ Iterator Time Complexity

Tags: c++, iterator

I've recently learned that we can add a C++ iterator with an offset in addition to using `++`.

For example,

```
unordered_map<int, string> um;
auto it = um.begin();
it += 5;
```

What is the time complexity of that `it += 5` ?

If it is O(1) then must all objects in `um` have equal lengths? Because otherwise, how would C++ know the address where the 5th object in the map starts?

For example,
If we have something like `auto it = unordered_set<int>::iterator`, then it makes sense because all elements in the set have the size of an `int`. So C++ can just increase it by something like `size_of(int) * 5`. But for elements in the map `um` above, since the key has type `string`, whose size varies depending on the length of the string. How can C++ know the address?

Comment: `since the key has type string, which doesn't have a fixed size.` It does have a fixed size.

Comment: @tkausl do you mean all strings are reserved the same amount of memory, regardless of their lengths?

Comment: if so, then the += operation on iterators is truly O(1)?

Comment: `do you mean all strings are reserved the same amount of memory, regardless of their lengths?` No, I mean that a `std::string` has a fixed size, no matter the string it actually holds. `if so, then the += operation on iterators is truly O(1)?` depends on the iterator. For linked lists, this would be impossible.

Comment: It depends on the type of iterator. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

Comment: an iterator is something completely different than an array or an address of an element. And fyi: A `std::string` does not contain the character data in the object itself (omitting SSO here). But it keeps a pointer to a dynamically allocated string.
Hence why @tkausl comment is correct: std::string is always the same size